# Create a hierarchical taxonomy list in Wordpress

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

First of all I want to thank all of your for reading my post and trying to answer my question. I'm having an issue regarding the taxonomies of Wordpress.

I created a website with a custom taxonomy and placed them in the backend in Hierarchy. The goal for me is to display al the taxonomies in hierarchical way on my wordpress site. For now i managed to echo the list on alphabetical order.

Are there guys around who can help me with creating a Hierarchical way of showing the taxonomies?

My code:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms( 'locations', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) ); ?>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) : ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <div class="module">
                            <div class="module-content">
                                <h4><Bekijk een wijnland</h4>
                                <div class="row">                                   
                                    <ul class="not-found-links">
                                        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ): ?>
                                            <li class="col-sm-4">
                                                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term, 'locations' ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?></a>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                </div><!-- /.row -->        
                            </div><!-- /.module-content -->             
                        </div><!-- /.module -->
                    </div><!-- /.col-* -->
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.not-found-content -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /.content -->
```

I placed the taxonomies in a table. See: http://winelisting.nl/wijnlanden/.

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Brent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_list_categories()` and pass in your custom taxonomy as an argument like so:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'     => 'locations',
    'orderby'      => 'name',
    'hide_empty'   => false,
    'show_count'   => false,
    'pad_counts'   => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'title_li'     => ''
);
?>

<ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/